# What does (SB-SYS:WAIT-UNTIL-FD-USABLE 6 :INPUT NIL NIL) do?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am curently using sbcl 1.0.57.0 and my program generates constant output at the shell, until at a certain point my program freezes without any clue whatsoever.

C-c and down, reveals the last call to be:

```
(SB-SYS:WAIT-UNTIL-FD-USABLE 6 :INPUT NIL NIL)
```

I restarted my program and tried this again, and again the program freezes and a C-c down reveals this call to be the last one. After a while, I didn't measure the exact time but it should roughly be around 5min, the program continues for a short period of time and then freezes again.

To put the call into context:
The first familiar call in the trace is `drakma:http-request`. The complete call used by itself does not result in a freeze, though.

Now I wonder what this call actually does and if this could be the reason the program freezes?

As the second part of this question would be requesting you to be clairvoyant if the call has nothing to do with my problems my final question is: **What does this call do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(describe 'sb-sys:wait-until-fd-usable) gives:

```
WAIT-UNTIL-FD-USABLE names a compiled function:
Lambda-list: (FD DIRECTION &OPTIONAL TIMEOUT)
[...]
Documentation:
Wait until FD is usable for DIRECTION. DIRECTION should be either :INPUT
or :OUTPUT
TIMEOUT, if supplied, is the number of seconds to wait before giving up.
```

The intention of the call seems to be to wait (without any timeout)
until the file descriptor 6 is usable, but can the problem be that 
the function is called with 4 arguments while it expects 2 or 3?

Comment: as I am not calling this method, I cant tell. But as the program does not produce any error, I think it is actually more likely that the function changed and you quoted an old API.
Could you please also provide a link of your source?

Comment: The description of SB-SYS:WAIT-UNTIL-FD-USABLE that I quoted came
from sbcl 1.0.40.0.  In sbcl 1.1.0, the function has the following
signature and documentation.

`(defun wait-until-fd-usable (fd direction &optional timeout (serve-events t))`

`If SERVE-EVENTS is true (the default), events on other FDs are served while waiting.`

Answer (score 0):

Though technically I did not ask this I wanted to add my newest information on this topic in case anybody else is looking for this problem in a similar context.

The problem arose using `drakma:http-request`. I was now able to write a proof of concept for a specific request and posted this as an issue at the drakma github page. It appears that drakma does not provide a timeout in sbcl thus the `(SB-SYS:WAIT-UNTIL-FD-USABLE 6 :INPUT NIL NIL)` waits on information to arrive without a timeout in this case:
https://github.com/edicl/drakma/issues/67